# Continue list item background color to left of container

Tags: css

I created a to-do list and applied styling that sets even list items to have a light grey background color with `li:nth-child(even)`, but there's a gap to the left of these lines where the white doesn't continue due to setting `margin-left: 15px` for li elements. I would like the white to be filled in all the way to the left side of the container, but for the text to remain starting 15px to the right of it. How can I accomplish this? Here's the relevant CSS (view [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/NYLMwW) for more):

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  background: white;
  /* distance from the top of the first line of text to the top of the second */
  line-height: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  color: #666;
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

/* Sets color of even li elements */
li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

/* Sets appearance of span content (Bootstrap trash can icon) when user hovers over list item */
li:hover span {
  width: 40px; /* Applies to icon background */
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
margin-left:15px;
```

to

```
padding-left:15px;
```